Не происходит парсинг значения в текстовом поле
Почему при нажатии кнопки "Удалить" происходит вызов функции DeleteEmployee, но значению id ничего не присваивается? Выводит просто ошибку "Введены некоректные данные". Решил вывести содержимое переменной id после нажатия и увидел что в ней ничего не содержится, хотя в текстовое поле я ввёл число
@page "/employee"

@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory

<h3>Сотрудники</h3>

@if (errorMessage != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @errorMessage
    </div>
}
<div class="form_container">
    <EditForm Model="@this" OnValidSubmit="DeleteEmployee" FormName="deleteEmployeeForm">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <label>ID сотрудника:</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="id" required />

        <button type="submit">Удалить</button>
    </EditForm>
</div>

@code {
    private List<Classes.Employee> items;
    private string errorMessage;
    private string id = string.Empty;

    private async Task load()
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("MyAPI");
        try
        {
            items = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Classes.Employee>>("api/employee");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorMessage = "Не удалось загрузить данные: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await load();
    }
    private async Task DeleteEmployee()
    {
        var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("MyAPI");    


        if (int.TryParse(id, out int delid))
        {
            try
            {
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = "Не удалось загрузить данные: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Введены некоректные данные";
        }
    }
}



Очень странно. Я оставил только метод DeleteEmployee и форму ввода. Все работает как надо, число в переменную попадает.

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOGIbbFfVUCCuRYm
Можете посмотреть в консоли браузера, число передаётся.

Есть предположения почему у меня не работает то что должно работать?

А по ссылке работает? Если да ну смотрите что там у вас еще есть, у меня идей нет.
